# Nvidia DIGITS - more than top 5 predicted classes

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, nvidia-digits

I am using [nvidia-digits](/questions/tagged/nvidia-digits) to train a CNN and get predictions. However the `.../classify_one.json` returns top 5 predictions by default. I need a larger `n`, how can I modify my request param to get the top `n` for example?

I couldn't find anything in DIGITS documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try modifying the `accuracy_param` of your top `"Accuracy"` layer of the model's `prototxt` file. You should have something like

```
accuracy_param {
  top_k: 5
}
```

Change the `top_k: 5` to the number you wish to get, e.g., `top_k: 10` for getting top 10 classes.